# How much safe is it to keep a desktop computer in sleep state overnight?

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep, hibernate, security

So far, I'm putting it into hibernate state overnight, but it takes way too much time to resume. Probably because of all the installed software and two virtual machines I'm constantly running on my desktop PC, it takes dozens times longer to fully resume from hibernation than from sleep state.

It's a desktop computer so I don't care about power consumption and I've already got an uninterruptible power supply to protect it from possible power outages.

My question concerns more the safety of the RAM and motherboard. As far as I know, RAM should be provided with power all the time while in sleep mode. So the memory modules remain heated all this time, right?

So, what are potential problems with keeping a *desktop* computer in sleep state overnight that you guys can think of? After all, sleep mode was designed for short-time suspensions.

In case if it matters, my motherboard is Asus P8P67.

Comment: Modern computers are design to be left on.  I have a computer that only reboots to install Windows Updates and the rare times a random process doesn't behave itself.  How long your hardware actually lasts depends on the quality of hardware you have.  I purchase my computer in 2007 and have not replaced a single part.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with letting it sleep.  Most people just set the machine to sleep after N minutes and then don't worry about "putting it to bed".

Comment: I turn mine off - however 'cheap' or efficient it is to be in sleep mode, I'm not paying for it :)

Comment: @DaveRook If you switch it off and on every day, I _think_ that it is actually more expensive in terms of energy consumption that letting it sleep. A desktop consumes quite a bit of power when turning on.

Comment: @terdon - Thanks, it's good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using hybrid sleep. Gives a good Hibernate backup should there be a power loss during the night. Google "Sleep Vs. Hibernate Vs. Hybrid Sleep" for more info on what each does in Windows.

Comment: If you could post a good link for reference that would help improve this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving a PC running 24/7 is **not dangerous**.

I've been doing it for years- as I like mine to be available when I'm away from home so I can reach it via LogMeIn.

PCs are **designed to run continually**.

Just think about the PCs they have at security desks (on 24/7), hotel reception desks, nurse stations in hospitals, computers running in shop back offices, and many more- all on 24/7 with no problems.

These generally aren't server class systems- just ordinary workstations like yours at home.

Comment: How much more is your electrcity bill per annum from running your PC continuously?

Comment: Not much more: my PC is very power-efficient. My bill averages around $20/month (including an electric cooker) with my PC on constantly. I have a Radeon HD 7700, a capable graphics card which is extraordinarily power efficient- it draws all its power from the motherboard with no need for additional connections to the PSU. My previous graphics card had TWO additional connections to the PSU, and actually led to a VERY noticeable increase in room temperature. So my advice isn't for users with power-hungry gaming rigs.

Comment: Thats very power efficient